# how to make Thread safety and not thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, thread-safety

I have this code and I Wonder if it is thread safe or not!!

if it is thread safe, How to make it not safe and vice versa

```
namespace ThreadSafeTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var user = new User() { Id = i };
                method(user);
            }
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 1000; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                var user = new User() { Id = i };
                method(user);
            }
        });


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void method( User user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"the {user.Id} is {user.Id}{user.Id}");
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id  { get; set; }
}
}
```

it is complicated to understand the concept
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is thread-safe since there is no shared state (i.e. different threads aren't sharing the same object). The only 'shared-ness' is the call to `Console.WriteLine` which is [thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety).

As an example of how to make it not thread-safe, change:

```
static void method( User user)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"the {user.Id} is {user.Id}{user.Id}");
}
```

to:

```
private static List<User> list = new List<User>();
static void method( User user)
{
    list.Add(user);
    Console.WriteLine($@"the {user.Id} is {user.Id}{user.Id}");
}
```

since `list.Add` is [not thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety).

*Note that the above `list.Add` code may still **sometimes** work - but it is not **guaranteed** to work (and it will **definitely** fail if you run it for long enough).*

Comment: ok list.add is not thread safe but the method still is thread safe . bcs the user Id field get its value from user . My question is about how to make this method unsafe? Somewhere I read with ref it would be unsafe but I'm not sure

Comment: `method` is **not** thread-safe in the version I showed. If `list.Add` is not thread-safe, and `method` calls it then (by definition) `method` is also not thread-safe.

Comment: `Somewhere I read with ref it would be unsafe but I'm not sure` Where did you read this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679654/are-net-ref-parameters-thread-safe-or-vulnerable-to-unsafe-multithreaded-acces

Comment: Your code does not experience that issue since a) you aren't using ref b) you don't have two threads accessing the same shared object .